# xml child to multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

How can I display the individual data of each book in separate HTML pages and link them together with some form of `<a>Next book</a>` link?

```xml
<books>
    <book>
        <Title>Web Warrior Series Xml </Title>
        <Author>Mckinnon, A</Author>
        <Year>2003</Year>
        <lib-code>138326</lib-code>
        <publisher>Thompson Brook</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Title>Xml in Record Time</Title>                         
        <Author>Natanya Pitts,</Author>
        <Year>2016</Year>
        <lib-code>173134</lib-code>
        <publisher>Bpb</publisher>
    </book>
    <book>
        <Title>Xml in Easy Steps</Title>
        <Author>McGrath, M</Author>
        <Year>2009</Year>
        <lib-code>153615</lib-code>
        <publisher>Dreamtech</publisher>
    </book>
</books>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We aren't a code writing service so try and show us what you've tried first

Comment: I don't have any idea about this. Searched Internet can't able to find any answers. That's why I asked whether it is possible to do this thing to some people who are good in problem solving than teasing newbies

Comment: You are going to get yourself absolutely nowhere with that mentality. Learn to code, learn to problem solve. Do not rely on others to do hold your hand and solve your problems for you

Comment: https://www.educba.com/xml-parsing-in-javascript/